# Phonegap - communicating between plugin and service

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have created a plugin that starts a service and this is working fine. However I wish to be able to send variables to the running service from the plugin, and to get variables out of the service. I have researched broadcast/receivers and binding but haven't be able to to get any examples working with the code structure I am using below. Does anyone have any tips? I'm new to android development and pretty new to Java (but not programming) so there is a conceptual leap that I haven't quite got yet.

**Plugin**

```
public class IOIOconnect extends CordovaPlugin {
    private Context thiscontext;
    private Intent ioioService;

    // Handle calls from Javascript
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        // Call from javascript to startup the IOIO service
        if (action.equals("ioioStartup")) {
            this.ioioStartup(callbackContext); 
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Initialise IOIO service (Called from Javascript)
    private void ioioStartup(CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        // Initialise the service variables and start it it up
        thiscontext = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        ioioService = new Intent(thiscontext, HelloIOIOService.class);
        ioioService.putExtra("loadinterval", 800); // Set LED flash interval
        thiscontext.startService(ioioService);
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
public class HelloIOIOService extends IOIOService {
        private int interval = 100; 

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    // USUAL IOIO SERVICE STUFF
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {  
        // Service has been started
        super.onStart(intent, startId);


        // IOIO When service is started load external vars (if set)
        int loadinterval = intent.getIntExtra("loadinterval", -1);
        if(loadinterval>=0){ interval = loadinterval; }

        // Native IOIO stuff
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals("stop")) {
            // User clicked the notification. Need to stop the service.
            nm.cancel(0);
            stopSelf();
        } else {
            // Service starting. Create a notification.
            Notification notification = new Notification(
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher, "IOIO service running",
                    System.currentTimeMillis());
            notification
                    .setLatestEventInfo(this, "IOIO Service", "Click to stop",
                            PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(
                                    "stop", null, this, this.getClass()), 0));
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
            nm.notify(0, notification);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exact same problem: writing plugin for Salesforce Mobile SDK (based on Cordova 2.3.0).

My case: plugin and app is different android projects.

The solutions, is that you have to publish the `Service` in `AndroidManifest.xml` of the main (app) project. Remember to sign it with full qualified path and as exported, like this:

```
<service
    android:name="full.qualified.path.to.Service"
    android:exported="true">
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a working plugin which is used in this project:
https://github.com/opensystemsassociation/southendtransportresearch/tree/master/phonegap

The code's not tidy as its still in development, but the 'hacky' approach works fine so hopefully it will help someone along the line a bit